# how to convert pandas dataframe to binary pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, binary

I have a pandas dataframe:
1. sc_RNA seq dataframe (n_cells, a_genes): contains gene expression matrix.
[image: dataframe]

Now I need to convert these pandas dataframes into binary pandas data frames, where, if there is an expression or value it will give 1 and if there is no value or expression(0) it will give 0.
I want to know how I could convert this?

code to reproduce given pandas dataframe: google collab:
"

```
import sys 
python_modules_path = '/mypath' 
sys.path.append(python_modules_path) 
!pip install scanpy 
import scanpy as sc
import anndata
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import scipy
fn1 = '/gdrive/MyDrive/zebrafish_embryo/sc_rna/zf3_scRNA.h5ad'
adata1 = sc.read_h5ad(fn1)
df= adata1.to_df()
df
```

df is the pandas dataframe shown in the picture.
link of zf3_scRNA.h5ad:https://db.cngb.org/stomics/zesta/download/

I tried following to convert pandas dataframe to binary pandas dataframe: `pd.get_dummies(df)`     and got the same pandas data frame (df) as I input it. it didn't convert to binary pandas dataframe.

I really need help in this case.

Expected binary pandas dataframe:
[image: binary dataframe]

Comment: Try `df.ne(0.0)` ?

Comment: @ScottBoston thats give a boolean dataframe  with true, false.

Comment: oh.... add `.astype(int)` or `.mul(1)` at the end.